# glm::vec3 addition error with overloaded '[]'

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading, glm-math

I have an issue with stringing together multiple vector additions when also using overloaded [] operators that return glm::vec3.

I've solved the issue by "de-stringing" my additions (putting each one in it's own statement) but I'd really like to know why it was happening at all (maybe my [] operator is done wrong?).

`NVec` is a wrapper class for `std::vector<glm::vec3>` that has it's [] overloaded. The purpose of this is to handle out of bounds [] calls (bounds being whatever they need to be, not standard index bounds).

Operator

```
glm::vec3 &Terrain::NVec::operator[](int n)
{
    if(n>=0 && n < std::vector<glm::vec3>::size() &&      //special out of bounds checking
       n-(*i)*width*2 != width*2 && n-(*i)*width*2 != -1) //i is a pointer to an int somewhere
        return glm::vec3(std::vector<glm::vec3>::operator[](n).x);  //default [] operator for std::vector<glm::vec3>
    else{
        count--;              //keeps track of how many were out of bounds
        return glm::vec3(0);  //returns a {0,0,0} vector. I've tried this with return vec3(0,0,0) too
    }
}
```

Problem code:

`faceNormals` is an `NVec` full of triangle face normals, `tri1` is a `glm::vec3[3]` and `i1` to `i6` are indexes. And I literally run these cases in this order to get my results.

```
// Case 1
tri1[0] = faceNormals[i1]
     + faceNormals[i2]
     + faceNormals[i3]
     + faceNormals[i4]
     + faceNormals[i5]
     + faceNormals[i6]; //gives garbage results

// Case 2
tri1[0] =  faceNormals[i1];
tri1[0] += faceNormals[i2];
tri1[0] += faceNormals[i3];
tri1[0] += faceNormals[i4];
tri1[0] += faceNormals[i5];
tri1[0] += faceNormals[i6]; //tri1[0] contains correct values

// Case 3
glm::vec3 v1 = glm::vec3(faceNormals[i1]);
glm::vec3 v2 = glm::vec3(faceNormals[i2]);
glm::vec3 v3 = glm::vec3(faceNormals[i3]);
glm::vec3 v4 = glm::vec3(faceNormals[i4]);
glm::vec3 v5 = glm::vec3(faceNormals[i5]);
glm::vec3 v6 = glm::vec3(faceNormals[i6]);
glm::vec3 tri = v1+v2+v3+v4+v5+v6; //tri contains correct values!
```

So, yeah. It doesn't make any sense to me. I only get errors (weird data in `tri[0]`) when I string together vec3 additions *and* use my `[]` operators in the same statement.

Comment: You seem to be returning references to local variables. These are dangling references, since the objects they refer to only live in the scope of the function they are created in.

Comment: As already mentioned, try removing the `&` from your return and you should see a big difference.

Comment: @juanchopanza Yup, that fixed it. Thanks. So the reason it worked when I "destrung" the additions was that the `=` was creating a copy of the reference and using that rather than the reference in the next addition. That was a very confusing problem.